# Google Apps Script return array values and use them in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying return an array and use it in a javascript function, but it doesn't seem to work. My Code.gs is as follows:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function test() {
    var locations = [];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13q7pIeMUHll6_5xBUpBavaBqALt9fnFnOIO-Hwy_pFc/edit'),
    sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
    range = ss.getRange("D2:D4"),
    values = range.getValues();
    for (var r=1; r<values.length; r++) {
       var row = values[r];
       locations.push(row[0]);
    }
    return locations;
}
```

The function in my test.html looks as follows:

```
function hello() {
   google.script.run.test();
}
```

So I want to pass the array and its contents to the hello function in my test.html. How can I make this work?

Comment: this is another way to access spreadsheet data https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#calling_apps_script_functions_from_a_template

Comment: Tnx for the link but the problem is that getValues() returns an array in an array. So still have to loop it through to get the following structure: test1, test2. Instead of, [test1], [test2]. Therefore, I need to return an array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `withSuccessHandler()` method chained to your `google.script.run`:

```
function hello() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(injectHTML)
    .test();
}

//This captures the returned string from the server side code
function injectHTML(argReturnedArray) {
  //To Do - code to inject the HTML

};
```

Unfortunately, server side `.gs` code will only return a string.  But there's a way to deal with that.  Use:

```
JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

Your array is named `locations`.

```
return JSON.stringify(locations);
```

Now you need to convert the JSON string back to an array:

```
function injectHTML(argReturnedArray) {
  /* Put the array into the browsers window object in order to make the
  *  array named myReturnedArray available to all other functions.
  */
  window.myReturnedArray = JSON.parse(argReturnedArray);

  //To Do - code to inject the HTML
};

//Get the array in another function
function myOtherFunction() {
  //Get the array from the browsers window object
  var theArray = window.myReturnedArray;
  var i=0, thisElement="";
  for (i=0;i<theArray.length;i+=1) {
    thisElement = theArray[i];
  }
};
```

Comment: Interesting. Tnx for your comment, It returns the contents of my array now! But how can I use the `var myTwoD_Array` in another function? As the locations i'm returning need to be used in other functions as well.

Comment: Put the array into the browsers `window` object.  See updated answer.  You could create a global variable, or create a global object, then put the array into the global object, but putting it into the `window` object is the easiest and most straight forward.