# Dynamic chart in Google Sheets sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I would like to create a column chart that can be displayed and dynamically updated in the Google Sheets sidebar (without reloading the sidebar) from data in a spreadsheet. I understand how to call the sidebar and load a chart using Google Charts and JavaScript, but I running into the following issues:

- How do I pull the data from the sheet to populate the DataTable needed for the chart? Could I do this with scriptlets or is there a better way?
- How do I update the columns in the chart automatically to reflect when data is changed without the use of a button? I think that this can be done with a timeout function that calls the data from the sheet at regular intervals, but I am not sure how to update the columns.

The solution would preferably only use pure JS and Apps Script. Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="genderChart" style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px"></div>

<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  var genderMale = Math.random() * 100;
  var genderFemale = Math.random() * 100;
  var genderNB = Math.random() * 100;

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Gender');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Students');
    data.addColumn({role: 'style'});

    data.addRows([
      ['Male', genderMale, '#9fc5e8'],
      ['Female', genderFemale, '#d5a6bd'],
      ['Non-binary', genderNB, '#b7b7b7']
    ]);

    var options = {
      legend: {position: "none"},
      animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'in'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('genderChart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    updateData();

    function updateData() {
      var genderMale = Math.random() * 100;
      var genderFemale = Math.random() * 100;
      var genderNB = Math.random() * 100;
      chart.draw(data, options);
      setTimeout(updateData, 100);
    }
  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use scriplets if you wish but that requires reloading the entire page because scriptlets are evaluated on the server.  You can also us [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).  The latter does not necessarily require a complete reload but in somecases it might

Comment: Please provide a simple [mcve] to demonstrate your issues.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I've attached my current code. However, the updateData() function does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `google.script.run` to communicate with the Apps Script server-side code, which will get the values from the spreadsheet. In your case since you're requesting data from the server you'll have to use [success handlers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers). Here's a cutout of how it works:

Client side:

```
  //other stuff

  var SHEET_VALUES = [] // use as a global variable
  function drawChart() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData();

  //the rest of the code
  }

  function onSuccess(values){
    //the onsuccess handler holds the values returned in getData() in the values param
    SHEET_VALUES = values
  }
```

Server side:

```
function getData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A3") //getting the values from cells A1:A3
  var values = range.getValues()
  
  return values.flat()
}
```

Essentially what this does is to call the server-side function `getData()` from the sidebar. The `getData()` function returns the values of A1:A3 in the spreadsheet and then the success handler assigns these values to the global variable `SHEET_VALUES`. Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834171) for the idea to use a global variable.

Also, note that in your `updateData()` function you're trying to use `setTimeout()`, but you should be using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) if you want it to repeat periodically. I also decided to just call `drawChart()` over and over again but your approach may differ. With all that in mind here's a full sample based on your starting code which worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="genderChart" style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px"></div>
<script>
  
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  var SHEET_VALUES = []

  function drawChart() {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData();

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var genderMale = SHEET_VALUES[0];
    var genderFemale = SHEET_VALUES[1];
    var genderNB = SHEET_VALUES[2];
    data.addColumn('string', 'Gender');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Students');
    data.addColumn({role: 'style'});

    data.addRows([
      ['Male', genderMale, '#9fc5e8'],
      ['Female', genderFemale, '#d5a6bd'],
      ['Non-binary', genderNB, '#b7b7b7']
    ]);

    var options = {
      legend: {position: "none"},
      animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'in'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('genderChart'));
    chart.draw(data, options)
    
  }

  function onSuccess(values){
    SHEET_VALUES = values
  }

  setInterval(drawChart, 1000)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And also add this to your server-side:

```
function getData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A3")

  var values = range.getValues()

  
  return values.flat()
}
```

Here is the sample in action, updating the chart based on the sheet values every second:

[image]

##### Sources:

- [Communicate with server functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)
- [google.script.run reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this to display multiple charts? I have created a separate draw function for another chart, but it doesn't seem to ever draw the other chart on the page.

Comment: You can, but note that in addition to the new draw function you need a new global variable to use in your second draw function, a new success handler to set the global variable and a new server-side function to fetch the sheet data, pretty much doubling the code. You could rewrite the whole thing to have your functions take parameters so you can reuse them if you plan to have several charts.

Comment: I noticed that when using this code, the chart continually flickers when using the tooltips to the constant redraws. I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028988/google-chart-flickering-on-consecutive-data-load but I'm having difficulty understanding how this code works and how it can be adapted to my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!